# react-router link not receiving router in context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React and react-router to create a single page javascript application. Each page is it's own component. On one page I am able to create a Link component successfully and it works as intended. On another page I get the following error:

```
Warning: Failed Context Types: Required context `router` was not specified in `Link`.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'makeHref' of undefined
```

Here is the file where I set up my routes:

http://pastebin.com/WBeN9BZw

Here is the component where the link works (in the TeamRow component):

http://pastebin.com/HjG2d43M

Here is the component where the link doesn't work (line 31):

http://pastebin.com/pWb7j8Mk

I logged the contexts throughout the app to examine them and the only time it isn't an empty object is in the App component. What am I doing wrong in the TeamPage component that my Link isn't working? How come the context is empty in the HomePage component but the Link works?

Comment: I noticed that you are passing `team` but using `this.props.teamName`. Can you successfully create a Link in the TeamPage component?

Comment: What version of react-router? You're supposed to specify the contextType: router in each component that uses it.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. You don't need to specify `contextTypes` unless you explicitly use `this.context.router`; the context will still be passed to children that declare the context type (e.g. `Link`). Do you have a small example that reproduces the problem that we can run/experiment with?

Comment: @pherris yes on line 72 of the second file the Link works properly

Comment: @Colin i'm using version 0.13.3, I've tried specifying contextType in all my components but to no effect

Comment: @BinaryMuse I haven't successfully managed to isolate this behavior outside of my code I'm sharing here. 


Am I right in thinking that "this.context" should contain the router in all the child components? I'm trying to figure out why Link in HomePage would have it even though it's parent component TeamRow does not.

Comment: @Liam Yeah, as long as context is not "broken" it should be available to any `Link` in the tree.

Comment: @BinaryMuse So I've done some more research and I believe this might be an issue with requiring both 'react' and 'react-router' in browserify. The version of react that is packaged within react-router overwrites the reference to react that all the components are registered on. The reason that button doesn't work is because it's created on an AJAX callback, I can get it to work if I hardcode the ajax data in and create it right away. I guess right at the start the React reference is fine but then it's immediately overwritten or something?

Comment: @Liam That sounds plausible, but React is only a peer dependency of React Router. See if you have more than one React entry in your `npm ls`

Comment: @BinaryMuse Hm, I'm not seeing two reacts in my npm installs, so maybe I'm off base. The reason I thought this was that I was pursuing a different issue where React devtools would flash with my component tree and then show up as empty, but then started working when I commented out the react router requirement. This seems to be very similar to the "stuff breaks when created on an ajax callback" issue I'm having now.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue and opened a question over here before I noticed this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301994/react-router-webpack-typeerror-cannot-read-property-makehref-of-undefined

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your require to

```
// remove the react-router require
var {Link} = require('react-router');
```

or

```
// keep the react-router require    
var Link = ReactRouter.Link;
```